# Is this the Pandas equivalent of SQL Dense Rank over a Sorted Partition?

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, t-sql

I have the following SQL fragment I'd like to replicate in Python:

```sql
SELECT
   DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY a0.[field1], a0.[field2] ORDER BY a0.[field3] DESC)  AS [new_field]
   ...
FROM <table>
```

Here is my attempt, is this equivalent?

```py
df["new_field"] = df.groupby(["field1", "field2"])["field3"].rank(
    method="dense", ascending=False
)
```

Comment: Curiously, can't you answer this question (*is this equivalent?*) by reviewing data results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's equivalent as long as `field3` is numeric. Otherwise you need some manipulation such as

```
df['new_field'] = df.field3.rank(method='dense',ascending = False)
df['new_field'] = df.groupby(['field1','field2'])['new_field'].rank(method='dense').astype(int)
```

Comment: I was testing this today and seem to get the inverse of the right result. Are you sure the second ascending=False on the second line is needed? It gets the right result so far when ascending=False is just on the first line.

Comment: yes, you're right @MarkMcGown , I missed that part, now fixed.